# Sublime text auto semicolon

Tags: autocomplete, sublime-text

Is it possible to automatic add semicolon in sublime?

```
// 1
Route::get(|
// 2
Route::get(|);
```

After closing bracket insert `;` at the end of line?

Comment: You'd have to delete that semicolon every time you type `if (...)` or `for (...)` or `while (...)` and such.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the [Auto Semi-Colon](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Auto%20Semi-Colon) plugin. It does exactly what you ask for, and it works with version 2 and version 3 of Sublime Text.

Comment: And it works very well too, taking action in function call syntax but not getting confused by a for(;;) construct. Typing a semicolon inside a string doesn't get interpreted specially though, which is fair enough, so binding a key sequence to a macro that goes to the end of line and inserts the semicolon would handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt that this useful. Text editor has no way of knowing where are you going to end the line. Closing bracket does not indicate the end of the line. I am not sure what language are you programming in. But in most languages that use (), there are multiple scenarios when you would continue the line after closing bracket. Consider following examples in C:

```
if(condition)
{
   statement;
}
```

also

```
variable = functionA() + functionB();
```

and finally

```
object.methodReturningObject().method();
```

As you can see, you will end up manually deleting semicolon in all these cases (and many more)